# Angular Resource Custom Method Dynamic Address

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to make a dynamic address for an angular resource.  I am successful with a "simple" addition to the base address, but once I add a forward slash, I get %2 added to the url, and my server, of course, sends back a 404.

Example that works

```
.factory('SomeServiceName', function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/base/:dest, {}, {
        searchFoo: { method: 'GET', params:{ dest: 'searchFoo' }, isArray: true}
});
```

Example that doesn't work

```
.factory('OtherServiceName', function($resource) {
        return $resource('api/base/:dest, {}, {
            fooBar: { method: 'GET', params:{ dest: 'foo/bar' }, isArray: true}
    });
```

Now if I add a more complex address as the dest param I get the %2 characters

POST /api/base/%2foo%2bar 404 2ms

I'm inheriting this type of code, and it may not be the best way, but I'd like to see if I can 1. get it to work the way I'd like or two get the "right" way set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the slashes á la

```
'foo\/bar'
```

Comment: Yeah I thought that would do it (should have mentioned it in the post)

Comment: And what would be "Two. get the right way" that the OP asked? I'm also interested.